# Acquire an image of the hard disk from the outside

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, password

I need to take a dd image of a MacBook (Model A2179) 's hard disk.

I have no way to recover the password to access the system and I want to acquire an image of the main hard disk for forensic purposes. If it uses encrypton, cloning it with the whole encryption would also be fine.

Is it even possible to do such thing? How would I proceed? I see booting from external media is impossible